# Linear maping, odd and even functions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $E$ be the vector space of all the mapings of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $F$ and $G$ be the set of all the even and odd functions of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I need to show that $E = F \oplus G$... The way I see this question, they are asking us to prove that every single linear maping of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a unique sum of an odd with an even function... I just don't know how to tackle this!

Comment: $f(x)=\frac {f(x)+f(-x)} 2+\frac {f(x)-f(-x)} 2$

Comment: In the book I'm using, they seem to make a distinction between mapings and functions, but you seem to use them interchangeably... why is it?

Comment: What's the distinction they make?

Comment: @OsamaGhani after some thinking and searching I guess its just semantics... Now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since for every function $f$ we can write $f(x)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\dfrac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$, where the first fraction is an even function and the second is and even function, follows $E=F+G$. Remains to show that $F\cap G=\{0\}$. Let $f\in F\cap G$, so $$f(x)=f(-x)=-f(-x)\Rightarrow2f(-x)=0\Rightarrow f(x)=f(-x)=0.$$